# Graph API - How to get friends name for their like id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I tried to get feed from user account. I am able to get the feeds from the following command.

```
$feed = $fb->get('/me/feed?fields=comments,likes', $access_token );
```

I can get the comments with ID and Name
But the likes are only giving ids of friends/users.

How do i get the users' name who liked that post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the names for likes: `/me/feed?fields=comments,likes{id,name}`

You do get the names for comments already, just debug the response of your API call. There is a "comments" field with "data > from".

Comment: Is there a way to get their gender?

Comment: no, of course not. you can just try by adding "gender" to the field list

Comment: I tried that, which returned field does not exist error. That is why i asked you.